# I can SSH but can't SFTP

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, sftp

I am dumfounded at this issue.  Brand new Ubuntu 12.04 Server install, I can SSH in, but can't use SFTP (Using Filezilla).  It seems to authenticate fine ..  But then it errors:

The error is:

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Here is the full transaction:

```
Status: Connecting to 10.2.1.102...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "username@10.2.1.102" 22
Command:    Trust changed Hostkey: Once
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Here is my sshd_conf file:

```
Port 22

Protocol 2

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768


SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO


LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes


IgnoreRhosts yes

RhostsRSAAuthentication no

HostbasedAuthentication no

PermitEmptyPasswords no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes


AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes
```

I am going around in circles, I don't know what to check next etc ..  Any help guidance on what to check next and or test, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the directory you're trying to SFTP to ? I think root has to own the repertory that is its parent (long time I did that).

Comment: Set `LogLevel DEBUG`, restart the ssh service and check your logs on the server side.

Comment: I am connecting to `/var/www`  User `root` owns `var` and the connecting user `username` owns `www`.  Does this need to change?

Comment: Done, where can I view the logs?  There is no
 /var/log/ssh

Comment: In Debian and derivatives, it's `/var/log/auth.log` if you didn't change the stock syslog configuration.

Comment: hum actually I may be wrong about that, it's when you want to jail a user to a particular place... sorry. It should work like this, like dawud said look at the logs. By the way any special feature you want to use with SFTP, why no SSHFS ?

Comment: @dawud ...  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!  The log pointed out a fundamental flaw in our network settings ..  Once corrected, it works like a charm!  If you would like to elaborate for others setting logging to debug and location etc, I will gladly accept and vote up!  Thanks!

Comment: Check if you have: root@crm-dev [~]# grep -i sftp /etc/ssh/sshd_config Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Answer (score 4):

FileZilla has done this to me in the past to. The problem was that filezilla tryed to use the ftp protocol when in fact sftp was needed even when i entered port 22 as my port. 
To solve this, enter: sftp://YOUR_IP_HERE as your host.

Comment: From provided log, it's clear the SFTP is used in this case ("fzSftp started" and "Trust changed hostkey")